# Как сменить цвет таблицы в backpack for laravel?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Есть в админке таблица с отзывами [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сменить цвет фона, если публикация "на модерации"?

Первый раз имею дело с этой админкой.
Все что смог раскопать файл feedback.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Feedback\Models;

use App\Core\Models\BaseModel;

use App\Core\Traits\AdminTrait;
use App\Core\Traits\ViewTrait as BaseTrait;
use App\Modules\Feedback\Traits\ViewTrait;
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Feedback extends BaseModel
{
    use CrudTrait, BaseTrait, ViewTrait;

    /**
     *  list published
     */
    const PUBLISHED_LIST = [
        self::ACTIVE => 'Опубликовать',
        self::NOT_ACTIVE => 'На модерации'
    ];

    /**
     *  list published
     */
    const PUBLISHED_LIST_COLUMN = [
        self::ACTIVE => 'Опубликовано',
        self::NOT_ACTIVE => 'На модерации'
    ];
    
    /**
     *  count show in main
     */
    const COUNT_SHOW_IN_MAIN = 2;

    /**
     *  count show in list feedback page
     */
    const COUNT_SHOW_IN_LIST = 10;

    /**
     *  count show in doctor page
     */
    const COUNT_SHOW_IN_DOCTOR_PAGE = 2;

    /**
     *  how much show random feedback in single page
     */
    const COUNT_SHOW_SHUFFLE = 2;

    /**
     *  how much symbol show
     */
    const COUNT_SYMBOL_IN_SHORT_FEEDBACK = 300;
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $table = 'feedbacks';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    // public $timestamps = false;
    // protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'age', 'text', 'doctor_id', 'active'];
    // protected $hidden = [];
    // protected $dates = [];
    protected $parentList = 'otzyvy';
    protected $urlField = 'id';


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | FUNCTIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * @param int $limit
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getListForMain(int $limit)
    {
          return self::isActive()->inRandomOrder()->get()->take($limit);
//        return self::isActive()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()->take($limit);
    }

    public function getListDoctors()
    {
       $doctorNames = DB::table('doctors')->select('id','h1', 'url', 'speciality', 'experience',
           'education', 'certificates', 'professional_skills', 'work_experience',
           'image', 'meta_title', 'meta_description', 'sort', 'active', 'image_full',
           'price')->get();
        if ($doctorNames)
        {
            return $doctorNames;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $limit
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getListWithPaginate(int $limit)
    {
        return self::isActive()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($limit);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function findActiveById(int $id)
    {
        return self::isActive()->findOrFail($id);
    }

    /**
     * @param int $doctorId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getByDoctorId(int $doctorId)
    {
        return self::whereDoctorId($doctorId)
            ->isActive()
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get()
            ->take(self::COUNT_SHOW_IN_DOCTOR_PAGE);
    }

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | RELATIONS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function doctor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Event::fire('Doctors.getClassName', [], true));
    }
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SCOPES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | ACCESORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | MUTATORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
}
```

Comment: а где код views?

Comment: Вы этот файл имеете ввиду? views.php ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jKeYLQ

Comment: Не совсем, фалй лежит в resources/views/...

Comment: Возможно этот. Ибо в views  кроме welcome.blade нет файлов. Раскопал list.blade.php в views>backpack>crud https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRqrVK

Comment: Похоже на правду, но все же что-то не то - очень трудно разобраться в системе на ощупь